# How to remove the Use by default checkbox in Google Drive Manage apps console

Tags: google-drive-api

[image: manage apps console page]

As a developer ,I want my apps hide the Use by default checkbox , just like what HelloFax do.

where can I set this?

We try to empty the MIME and extension setting,but we got

[image]

Does that means I can not remove the Use by default checkbox if my app does not support creating new documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list MIME types and extensions that the app can open by default in the Drive SDK section of the APIs Console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Leave both "Default MIME Types" and "Default File Extensions" empty to hide the checkbox.

EDIT: If your app has no primary type, you need to specify at least one type (or extension) as secondary or allow it to create new files.

This is because of the new security model which only grant access to files that a user has created with a given Drive app or files that a user opens with a given Drive app:

https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview#granting_file-level_access

Comment: So in this case our app can not remove the checkbox like HelloFax. Am I right?

Comment: This might be a bug, we are investigating it. You should be allowed to specify secondary types only and not enable Create New. Please bear with us a bit more.